# root user has no enough space issue in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, diskspace

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 and facing issue `root user has no enough space,`
[image]

As shown in above image /dev/nvme0n1p8 has 27 GB items, How can I see those items in my disk and can remove them so that I can have enough space ?

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, it would be better to ask on one of the sites listed in the Linux tag description.

Comment: snap and docker can eat a lot of space. You could delete, temporarily, some non-vital container then analyze the problem with more comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is full, you may be not able to add a tool to monitor your disk usage, like `ncdu`

- However, some directories can be cleaned easily :

  > check files you need or not

  ```sh
  /tmp
  /var/log/
  ```
- Snaps are size consuming too, it holds multiple versions of the same package (rollback feature):

  https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html

**Check files before deleting**